# JSON.parse(' ') - where is the source code in nodeJs or JS or V8?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
JSON.parse(fileName_or_stringOfJSON)
```

I know they return an object, but how is the string converted into object. In NODEJs, where is the source code?

Comment: Sample data and explanation would be helpful!

Comment: Why in the world would you need the source code for that?

Comment: There is no sample, we all know how JSON.parse() works. I want to know where is the source of FUNCTION JSON.PARSE() comes from

Comment: @AbanaClara, I am trying a new project where I am praising the user string. I am continously trying a lot different ways non are satisfying. I know JSON.PARSE() is breaking string into object so interested in seeing that

Comment: @AbanaClara For curiosity's sake, for one :)

Comment: Enjoy ~ https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/json-parser.cc

Comment: Betting @Phil found that in a 15 second web search.

Comment: Well, Google seemed to want to link to the header file (`json-parser.h`) so it took a couple of seconds to load up the `src` directory and Ctrl+F for _"json-parser.c"_

Answer (score 1):

I think JSON.parse() is not a utility solely usable in Nodejs. It is already standardized since Javascript v1.7 if I am not mistaken. If you are interested in "how" question, read [this](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.12.2).

Comment: I think OP is literally after the source code. As such, this question is off-topic (_"off-site resources"_). Nice link though

Comment: I think he/she is looking at how parse works. Pseudocode might help, and this is a good lead.